# Closing Div on Click not working in Chrome but is in all other browsers

Tags: javascript, jquery, joomla1.7

I just finished building a Joomla website for a client and of course on the day of launch I am having a problem with the Chrome browser not closing a specified div on click. I have tested in every other browser and it works fine. Is there any way I could rewrite this code so it would work in Chrome.. and of course all the others?

I'm closing a div that houses a flash animation after some time.

JavaScript:

```
<script> 
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#flashcntr").click(function() {
            setTimeout(function() {
                $("#flashcntr").addClass("hide");
            }, 2000); 
        });
    });
</script>
```

Style in the head:

```
<style type="text/css">
    .hide  { display: none !important;}
</style>
```

Please help! :) loosing hair :(

Comment: it works fine for me in a jsFiddle... could you post your html as well?

Comment: Here is the link, try it in Chrome: http://thestageisset/cincyusa.com. I tried all of the suggestions and it still isnt working in Chrome :(

Comment: I assume the URL is this: http://thestageisset.cincyusa.com/

Comment: Yes that url is correct.

Comment: the element you want to click is under the flash object.

Comment: So being that its flash how do I tell Chrome that the click I want to start the timeout effect is in the flash?

Comment: see my answer below, it should help

Answer (score 2):

`$("#flashcntr").addClass("hide");` would be better off as `$("#flashcntr").hide();`

see http://api.jquery.com/hide/

**edit:**
it seems your flash object is sitting *over* your `#flashcntr` element. through the DOM editor, i set the width of `flashcntr` to 1024px and set the bg color to #f0f so you could see the clickable region. I then clicked it and it hid after the two seconds timeout.

I suppose I would ensure that the `z-index` on the flash object is set to a lower index than the `flashcntr` element.

**edit2:** to achieve your desired effect, set the flash object `position` to `relative` and `z-index` to -1 (that's minus one). You should then be able to click the `flashcntr` element, so the flash object's style attribute looks like this:

```
style="z-index:-1; position:relative; visibility:visible;"
```

Comment: Could I use a z-index to bring it forward?

Comment: I added that via object#flashid on my stylesheet and if you click it the flash doesnt run but it does disappear. I do need the curtains to open... any other thoughts?

Comment: Humm, I wasn't aware you wanted to retain the flash animation. If you wanted to kind of mimic it a little, you could try replacing your `.hide()` with `.slideUp('fast')` to give the curtain an effect of being raised? Alternatively, you could look into the ExternalInterface JavaScript-Actionscript interactions to control Flash objects through JS. However, if the "Open" button triggers the curtain event, why don't you just change the scope of the button to the entire flash object?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the option of just removing it from the DOM? Or do you give the user the option of 'bringing it back later' w/out a page reload?

You may just try:

```
 jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
     $("#flashcntr").click(function() {
          setTimeout( function() {
                      $("#flashcntr").remove();
                    }, 2000);
     });
 });
```

That will remove it from the DOM completely. And if you wanted to give them the option of bringing it back, you **could** just load a snippet via Ajax and insert it back:

```
 $("#putitback").click(function() {
     $.get("myflash.html").appendTo("#somediv");
 });
```

I find I'm often having to do elaborate stuff like this for Chrome to behave like all other browsers.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you've tried the jQuery hide function or not, but it would be like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#flashcntr").click(function() {
        setTimeout(function() {
            $("#flashcntr").hide();
        }, 2000); 
    });
});
```

If that still doesn't work, I would try using the Developer -> Javascript Console in Chrome and put in `$("#flashcntr").hide();` and see if it hides the button.

If that does work, from there, you can add a console log to see if you're making it into the .click function. The console.log statement will show up in the javascript console.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#flashcntr").click(function() {
        console.log('button clicked');
        setTimeout(function() {
            $("#flashcntr").hide();
        }, 2000); 
    });
});
```

Comment: I have tried the .hide function. It seems like its not even getting to the code to read the setTimeout function.